# How do I add Chrome to my path

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to use [Flammarion](https://github.com/zach-capalbo/flammarion) and its instructions state that I should ensure that chrome is on my path.  The Chrome app appears to be at `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app`. How do I actually add this to my path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to edit your `.bash_profile` which is located in your home directory.

I don't reccommend using TextEdit to modify this file, use `vi` or `nano` in Terminal instead

### Open Terminal in home directory

You should be at your home directory but to be sure, just type:

`$ cd ~`

### Edit .bash_profile

`$ nano .bash_profile`

Your's may not even exist so you may just start off with a blank screen.  Not to worry, each is totally customizable.

If you don't have a PATH statement in there already, just add the following to a new line:

`export PATH="/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH"`

(BTW, I am assuming your software wants the path to the actual Google Chrome binary).

If you alredy have a paths statement, append the path to Chrome to the existing statement and separate it with a colon:

#### Before:

```
export PATH=/path/to/some/stuff
```

#### After:

```
export PATH=/path/to/some/stuff:/path/to/more/stuff
```

Hit Ctrl X to exit.  You will be asked if you want to save; say yes.

### Restart Terminal & Test

Quit that shell and start it again so your changes can take effect.

To ensure that your path now reflects your changes, type the following command:

`echo $PATH`

Your new path should now show the Google Chrome directory.  To further test it, in the Terminal window at in your home directory type `"Google Chrome"` and Chrome should launch.

Comment: We are on OSX. Just edit paths.d.